# How to combine linear model with step function

Tags: r, glm, lm

Suppose we have this data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

set.seed(42)
d1 <- tibble(x =  0:49, y = 5*x  + rnorm(n = 50))
d2 <- tibble(x = 50:99, y = 10*x + rnorm(n = 50))
data <- rbind(d1, d2)   
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

How to fit that data?

What I tried:

**Linear model**

```r
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = data)
data %>%
  add_predictions(m1) %>%
  gather(key = cat, value = y, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = cat)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**Step function**

```r
# step model
m2 <- lm(y ~ cut(x, 2), data = data)
data %>%
  add_predictions(m2) %>%
  gather(key = cat, value = y, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = cat)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**How to combine both?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically, your model takes the form

```
    { a_0 + a_1 x  when x < 50
y = {
    { b_0 + b_1 x when x >= 50
```

You can combine this with indicator functions to arrive at a form in a one-line equation:

```
y = a_0 + (b_0 - a_0) * 1[x >= 50] + a_1 * x + (b_1 - a_1) * x * 1[x >= 50] + error
```

Simplifying, we could write this as:

```
y = c_0 + c_1 * x + c_2 * z + c_3 * x * z + error
```

Where I'm writing `z = 1[x >= 50]` to emphasize that this indicator function is just another regressor

In R, we can fit this like

```
lm(y ~ x * I(x >= 50), data = data)
```

Where `*` will fully interact `x` and `1[x >= 50]` as desired.

```
with(data, {
  plot(x, y)
  reg = lm(y ~ x * I(x >= 50))

  lines(x, predict(reg, data.frame(x)))
})
```

[image]

If you don't know that the jump happens at 50, the road is wide open, but you could for example compare mean squared errors:

```
x_range = 1:100
errs = sapply(x_range, function(BREAK) {
  mean(lm(y ~ x * I(x >= BREAK), data = data)$residuals^2)
})
plot(x_range, errs)
x_min = x_range[which.min(errs)]
axis(side = 1L, at = x_min)
abline(v = x_min, col = 'red')
```

[image]